# "I have been sent" or "I am sent"?

Tags: tense, present-perfect, present-tense

I was asked to work with my friend's friend whom I don't know. As I enter his room, he asks me:

> Who is this?

I reply:

> This is James. I **have been/am** sent here by Ory.

Which one is appropriate, *have been sent* or *am sent*?

Answer (score 3):

Since the sending happened in the past (maybe just a few seconds ago, but in the past), you should use either the simple past tense (preterite):

> I was sent here.

or the present perfect:

> I have been sent here.

Comment: -1 doesn't answer the question (doesn't deal with the grammatical *I am sent* except to ignore it or imply that it should not be used).

Answer (score 0):

1. I am is the present simple form. you can't use it. Because, someone has sent you. The action sending started in the past and The result sending is still happening now.
   If you want to use "I" then you should use I was sent. past simple passive.
2. I have been sent is ok. It present perfect passive

Answer (score 0):

"I am sent" an old-fashioned if not obsolete form. It suggests to me a biblical or other religious text, and not a recent one:

> I am sent to bring salvation.

Do not use this form for everyday meanings.

The usual form would be the simple past:

> I was sent by Ory.

the form

> I have been sent by Ory.

is a bit more formal and in my view does not flow as well, but has the same meaning in this case.

---

By the way "This is John" is awkward and not natural when speaking about yourself. It would be the usual form to introduce another person. To introduce oneself, say "I am John." or "My name is John."